# Short Id generation and maximum number of combinations

Tags: c#, combinations

Okay this is probably more a maths question but since its related to programming and my web application i'll ask here first:

I'm trying to create short id's that are 8 characters long .  The "pool" to draw the id from is a combination of numbers, upper and lower case letters.

```
string charPool = "ABCDEFGOPQRSTUVWXY1234567890ZabcdefghijklmHIJKLMNnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

And if you're interested here's the method:

```
private string GenerateRandomCode(int length)
{
    string charPool = "ABCDEFGOPQRSTUVWXY1234567890ZabcdefghijklmHIJKLMNnopqrstuvwxyz";
    StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        rs.Append(charPool[(int)(_random.NextDouble() * charPool.Length)]);
    }

    return rs.ToString();
}
```

How many possible combinations are there for 8 character id's?  Grateful if you can post the equation as well :)

Thanks

Comment: options per slot ^ number of slots = number of combinations. a-z is 26, times 2 (for uppers as well) is 52, plus 10 (0-9) is 62. Each ID is 8 chars long, so the result is 62^8, which is pretty big: 218,340,105,584,896 possible unique ID's. I would suggest generating them without any random mechanism.

Comment: No, its an actual MVC Web App im working on - Why does it matter?

Comment: The integer overloads of Random.Next() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5.aspx would be cleaner.

Comment: I see what you mean - int.maxValue should cover most use cases.  Guess it's a question of scalability although int.maxvalue should return a sensible number of possible values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options per slot ^ number of slots = number of combinations`

a-z is 26, times 2 (for uppers as well) is 52, plus 10 (0-9) is 62. Each ID is 8 chars long, so the result is 62^8, which is pretty big:

`218,340,105,584,896 possible unique ID's`

I would suggest doing:

`_random.Next(charPool.Length - 1)`

(and saving `charPool.Length - 1` in a variable outside of the loop), instead of:

`_random.NextDouble() * charPool.Length`

Because you might get an exact `1.0` with `.nextDouble()`, which means you will be accessing the array at an index that equals the length, and you will get IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: Why not use random? In the web app we will check for collisions, is that not enough?

Comment: Check for collisions and re-generate if collided? I suppose... But if you don't mind the ID's being generated in a logical order, I would suggest some other algorithm. I'm working on it right now and will post my suggestion soon.

Comment: Great thanks - Part of the solution to be the problem is to avoid people "guessing" the next id

Comment: Would you like to allow a single character to appear more than once? Example: "ab88a2ab" - is this valid? I suppose you do, and in that case, turns out, it really is a good way to go with randoms. If you wanted to go through all possible options in a logical manner, that would be another case, though. Anyway, see my edit for an important fix in your code.

Comment: Absolutely, "ab88a2ab" is valid